# How can I split a long string into 3 letter bins in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have a long string of letters in a cell, how can I bin the string into 3 letter groups, without them overlapping in excel? My actual strings are 100s of letters long.

e.g.

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO  =  ABC  DEF  GHI  JKL  MNO

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using Microsoft 365 you could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=MID(A1,SEQUENCE(,CEILING(LEN(A1),3)/3,,3),3)
```

Comment: You can omit `TRANSPOSE()` by using `=MID(A1,SEQUENCE(,LEN(A1)/3,,3),3)`.

Comment: @Harun24HR, yeah, I just noticed. Thanks for the headsup. I also added in an nested `CEILING()` to capture any trailing characters in their own group of either 1 or 2 chars.